# JSON request fails trying to retrieve data by passing in array using linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, controller

I am working on a MVC 5 application. I have a method in the controller that accepts 5 parameters, one of which is a integer array. This array would be used to retrieve specific information from the db based on the values contained in it.

The code for the controller method is shown below:

```
public JsonResult varyByStudyPeriod(int buildingId, int baselineLocationId, int baselineStandardId, int baselinePeriod, int [] altPeriod)
    {
        var data = from r in db.ResidentialDatas
                   where r.BuildingId == buildingId
                   && r.LocationId == baselineLocationId
                   && r.StandardId == baselineStandardId
                   && r.Year == baselinePeriod
                   //&& altPeriod.Contains(r.Year)
                   select new { r.LCC, r.Year };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Year is simply just integers from 1 to 40 in the db.

However, the commented line is where the Json request fails. Is it possible to guide me in the right direction?

The url for the JSON request is shown below. The format seems to be the issue as the method does not retrieve the information requested.

```
/ResidentialBuilding/varyByStudyPeriod?buildingId=1&baselineLocationId=1
    &baselineStandardId=1&baselinePeriod=1&**altPeriod=2,3**
```

Comment: _How_ does it fail? Are you getting an exception? Do you get actual data for `altPeriod` or is it null?

Comment: I just updated the url for the Json Request. The format of the altPeriod seems to be the issue when the method attempts to query the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your query parameter isn't providing `altPeriod` in a form the default model binder can understand. If you *can't* change the format the caller is using, you could change the `altPeriod` parameter type to `string` and just split it into integers yourself. If you *can* change the caller, you could change the way it builds the query string so that it looks like this:

```
?buildingId=1&baselineLocationId=1&baselineStandardId=1&baselinePeriod=1&altPeriod=2&altPeriod=3
                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The duplication of the `altPeriod` parameter will tell the model binder that all those values belong together and they'll all end up in your array.